# Display current system time in msgbox

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-6

I got error when I compile the following code, the error tells me that I have to convert unsigned short to char, i dont know how to perform this conversion. I'm using vc6 MFC. This is the code I used.

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);
unsigned short time = st.wHour;
MessageBoxA(TEXT(time),"system time",MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `std::ostringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

...

std::ostringstream time;
time << st.wHour;
MessageBoxA(time.str().c_str(),"system time",MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `time` is an integer, while `MessageBoxA` wants a string. You have to convert the integer to a string, which is not done by the `TEXT` macro. I suggest you read up more on either `std::stringstream` or possibly `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

or ...

char str[20];

sprintf(str,"%d",st.wHour);

MessageBoxA(str,"system time",MB_OK);

Rodd Taylor

Saudi Arabia

Comment: Given that this is an MFC project, I think CString::Format() would be preferable to sprintf().